# Write 2d array into a text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I need to write a 2D randomized array with a size of `[5][3]` into a text file. How can I write it in a single line in the text file? The output that I got from the file is in matrix form, not in a single line. The reason why I want to write it as a single line is that I want to write another array called max for the second line in the text file (I also don't know how to code this).

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

process = 5
resources = 3
allocation = [[0 for i in range(resources)]for i in range(process)]

def writeFile(allocation, process, resources):
file = open("test.txt", 'w')
for i in range(process):
    for j in range(resources):
        allocation = random.randint(10, size=(5, 3))
file.write(str(allocation))
file.close()

return

if __name__ == '__main__':
writeFile(allocation, process, resources)

file = open("test.txt", 'r')
allocation = np.array(file.readlines())
print(*allocation)
file.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by single line? Row followed by other rows without and formatting i.e a single number line?

Comment: @melarCoder
Single line means like this: [[0,1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [0, 0, 2]]
But in the file, it is in a 2d arrayform

Answer (score 2):

```
allocation = []
def writeFile(allocation, process, resources):
    file = open("test.txt", 'w')
    for i in range(process):
        temp = list(random.randint(10, size=(resources)))
        allocation.append(temp)
    file.write(str(allocation))
    file.close()
    return
```

Your code was generating a random 5x3 matrix for each iteration. To write a single line to the file, I appended each row as a list and casted it as a string in the end. The output for the above code is:

```
[[0, 5, 9], [5, 4, 4], [7, 3, 9], [4, 6, 4], [9, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: Oh yes! This is what I'm looking for. Can I ask one more question? How to store it in a 2d array again when I read it and want to print the length of the array? Below is the code that I have tried but this error occurred "TypeError: len() of unsized object" 
    file = open("test.txt", 'r') 
    y = np.array(file.readline()) 
    print(y)
    print(len(y)) 
    file.close()

Comment: Refer to this answer for [converting a string representation of a list to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/13227971).